# Global variables static and non-static are initialized with default values are assigned by compiler or something else?

Tags: java, static, jvm, instance, compiler-optimization

A.I seen lot of programs in that every global variable assigned with their default value.
Is this initializing work done by compiler or JVM.

Answer (score 1):

> I seen lot of programs in that every global variable assigned with their default value. Is this initializing work done by compiler or JVM.

Strictly speaking, Java doesn't have "global" variables.  True global variables are visible everywhere without any qualification.  Java `static` variables need to be either qualified or imported to use them.

Default initialization of `class` variable is performed by the runtime system.  Indeed, a `class` variable is default initialized *first* even if it has an explicit initialization.  (Indeed, under some circumstances it is actually possible for a program to see the default-initialized value prior to the explicit initialization; refer to the JLS for an explanation.)

Having said that, it could never be strictly correct to say that the compiler initializes things.  The compiler generates a `.class` file containing code and other stuff.  But the variables that need to be initialized *do not exist* until *after* the compiled code has started to execute.  By that time, the compiler is well and truly finished.

> Default constructor is provided by compiler and of course it doesn't have a explicit return type is it returning anything implicitly.

No Java constructor has a return type.  And no Java constructor explicitly returns anything.  It is not really meaningful to ask if the constructor *implicitly* returns something.  At the bytecode level the sequence is something like this:

- The `new` bytecode is used to allocate the object in the heap
- A `dup` bytecode pushes a second copy of the object reference onto the operand stack
- Bytecodes codes are executed to evaluate the constructor arguments and push them onto the operand stack
- An `invokespecial` bytecode is used to call the relevant constructor pseudo-method.  This "consumes" the pushed reference (which becomes `this`) and the arguments.  No return value is pushed.
- On return to the calling code, the original reference on the opstack is then assigned or returned.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this initializing work done by compiler or JVM.

Depends on the value. If it's a so-called Compile Time Constant, then compiler. Otherwise VM. For example, `private static final long foo = System.currentTimeMillis();` would be done by the VM, so that'll end up storing in `foo` the point in time when the class containing this line is first loaded (which won't be system start, it'll be first time some code runs that refers to it). Something like `private static final long foo = 5;` is done by the compiler, as that's a compile-time constant.

> Default constructor is provided by compiler and of course it doesn't have a explicit return type is it returning anything implicitly.

All constructors cannot have a return type, that's... why they are called constructors.

At the class file level, a constructor is a special kind of method that returns the instance you're creating, but there's nothing in java (the language) you can do with that information.

Comment: Variables without a specific value are initialized to 0 or null.

Comment: – or `false`. Except local variables are not (they need to be explicitly initialized before their value is used). @NomadMaker